# SQL Auto assign a number to duplicating values that resets after a change in the values WITHOUT using ROW_NUMBER or Partition BY?

Tags: sql, ansi-sql-92

I would like to create a "count" or "order" field that would auto-increment, but restart after every change in a different field? In the table below, the "Order" field would restart at "1" every time there was a change in the "Meal" field. Thanks.

| Meal | Time | RowNumb |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Lunch | 10:30 | 1 |
| Lunch | 11:00 | 2 |
| Lunch | 11:30 | 3 |
| Dinner | 4:30 | 1 |
| Dinner | 5:00 | 2 |
| Dinner | 5:30 | 3 |
| Dinner | 6:00 | 4 |

I tried this:

```
SELECT
    t1.meal,
    COUNT(t2.meal) + 1 AS RowNumb
FROM CTE t1
JOIN CTE t2 ON t2.time < t1.time OR (t2.time = t1.time AND t2.meal <> t1.meal)
GROUP BY
    t1.time,
    t1.meal
ORDER BY
    t1.time;
```

But I am getting this:

| Meal | Time | RowNumb |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Lunch | 10:30 | 1 |
| Lunch | 11:00 | 2 |
| Lunch | 11:30 | 3 |
| Dinner | 4:30 | 4 |
| Dinner | 5:00 | 5 |
| Dinner | 5:30 | 6 |
| Dinner | 6:00 | 7 |

Comment: Please tag your question with the DBMS you are using - as the answer may be product-specific. Why don't you want to use ROW_NUMBER or PARTITION BY?

Comment: You select 2 columns, but your result has 3 columns...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a subquery to count the rows for the same meal and a time till then:

```
SELECT
  t.meal,
  t.time,
  (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM mytable t2
    WHERE t2.meal = t.meal
    AND t2.time <= t.time
  ) AS rownumb
FROM mytable t
ORDER BY t.meal, t.time;
```